# Is it possible to search for a specific key/value entry then, if found, delete the entire dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have a CSV file that I am iterating through as a list of dictionaries (imagine each row in an excel file represented by an individual dictionary composed of a column name and the value for that column).

Is there any way in which I can iterate through all the dictionaries, search for a specific key:value combination and, if found, delete the entire dictionary?  Essentially, if specific column == 99999 then delete the row (dictionary).

This is what I have and I am getting the 'list index out of range' error that seems to be 
common with this type of thing.

```
for i in range(len(csv_data)):
    column_name = 'specific_column'
    if csv_data[i][column_name] == '99999':
        del csv_data[i]
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Style of code where you use ``range(len(csv_data))`` is plain bad code in python, try to use ``for elem in csv_data`` when iterating over something.

Comment: @nes - its fine when you need the index (although enumerate is a good choice too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rebuild the list with a list comprehension, *keeping* rows instead:

```
column_name = 'specific_column'
csv_data = [row for row in csv_data if row[column_name] != '99999']
```

This creates a new list, replacing the old, where only dictionaries with the specific column *not* set to `'99999'` are kept.

You are getting an `IndexError` exception because your loop doesn't take into account that the list is getting shorter; you are looping from 0 to `N`, but as you delete, the last index of the list moves from `N - 1`, to `N - 2`, etc.

Moreover, as your `i` loops through the indices, you end up *skipping* rows, as `i` increments, but the next element in the list moves *down* the indices as you delete items in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, once you remove an item, the length of `csv_data` changes, and the `for` loop will iterate the wrong number of times. A different problem would occur if you iterate directly over `csv_data`. In that case you wont get an exception but the loop would skip some values (actually your current loop does too, but you don't notice due to the exception)

Instead of immediately deleting the objects you can save the indices to remove and remove them later:

```
to_be_removed = []
for i in range(len(csv_data)):
    column_name = 'specific_column'
    if csv_data[i][column_name] == '99999':
        to_be_removed.append(i)

for i in to_be_removed:
    del csv_data[i]
```

Alternatively you can just iterate over a copy and remove the elements from the original value:

```
for i, val in enumerate(list(csv_data)):
    if val[column_name] = '99999':
        del csv_data[i]
```

Or you can build a copy and avoid copying the elements that don't match the predicate:

```
copy = []
for val in csv_data:
    if val[column_name] = '99999':
        copy.append(val)
```